# componentWillUpdate is deprecated in React, how can I replace it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React 16.3.0 was released and there were changes in React lifecycles.

React does not recommend to use `componentWillMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate`.

In that case, what should I use instead of `componentWillUpdate`?
For example, in the following code how can I replace `componentWillUpdate`?

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";

class ModalContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    openModal: false
  };
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      openModal: !this.state.openModal
    });
  };

  escapeKey = e => {
    if (e.key === "Escape" && this.state.openModal === true) {
      this.setState({
        openModal: !this.state.openModal
      });
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add("no-scroll");
    this.componentWillUpdate(this.state, this.state);
  }
  componentWillUpdate(p, c) {
    if (c.openModal) {
      window.addEventListener("keyup", this.escapeKey);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", this.escapeKey);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keyup", this.escapeKey);
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <div className="ModalContainer">
        <a className={`ModalContainer-trigger`} onClick={this.onClick}>
          click here to open the modal
        </a>
        {this.state.openModal && (
          <Modal
            onClick={this.onClick}
            in={!!this.state.openModal}
            {...this.props}
          />
        )}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ModalContainer;
```

Thank you

Comment: In your current code posted you are only using one of those - the componentWillUpdate.

As per the documentation its replacement is a combination of getDerivedStateFromProps and getSnapshotBeforeUpdate.

Give those a try.

Comment: I don't see any `componentWillMount` in your code.

Comment: @DragonBorn sorry, i mean "what should I use instead of componentWillUpdate?"

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate

> getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() is invoked right before the most recently rendered output is committed to e.g. the DOM. It enables your component to capture some information from the DOM (e.g. scroll position) before it is potentially changed.

Btw, I think there's not much use case to use such method.

You can still use `componentDidUpdate` if you want to have side effects after any states changed.

---

This answer based on React16.6.3

Comment: that is what documentation says but it is triggered after render() method unlike the componentWillUpdate. so my replacement is shouldComponentUpdate

Answer (score 4):

I replaced it with `shouldComponentUpdate` because that is triggered before `render()` method is called just like with `componentWillUpdate`.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, precisely because it runs before render() is called. Simply return 'true' in order to retain the default behavior (i.e. render on every update) and you can do whatever else you need to in that function before the component updates.

Answer (score 2):

`getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` can be use in place of componentWillUpdate. But if you still want to use the same method then add  `UNSAFE_`

before the method.

> UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()

Note: It is not recommended to use UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate. The best alternative is `comoponentDidUpdate`

More info:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact question and luckily Google led me to an [article](https://medium.com/@benadamstyles/react-native-layoutanimation-in-the-post-componentwillupdate-age-9146b3af0243) that provided the answer.

The easiest solution is to move your `LayoutAnimation` into the `componentDidUpdate` event.

**Example:**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  LayoutAnimation.easeOut()
}
```

According to the above article, there was a tweet from Andrew Clark, a core contributor to React that the above event is

> called before the UI is painted

and finally:

> This means you can trigger a LayoutAnimation in componentDidUpdate(), and it will still apply to that same update when it finally gets painted to the screen.

Answer (score -6):

It's not a big problem, everything will still work, but those methods will probably be removed in React 17. Deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work, it just means there is a better replacement for it. If you use them while developing your app, you can use the new lifecycle methods described in the blog post below.

Everything is detailed here on the official React blog in THIS POST BELOW
[enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)

Comment: yes, it is working. But, I wonder how can update my code to the latest lifecycle method

Comment: componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { if (this.state.openModal) { window.addEventListener("keyup", this.escapeKey); } else { window.removeEventListener("keyup", this.escapeKey); } }  @Alfrex92

Comment: Consider providing suggested solution in the answer. [Link-only answers aren't considered good ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Also, 'enter link description here' link is just sloppy.

Comment: Not a solution. You can go with a comment instead of the answer.

Comment: This is a solution, but the link should be paraphrased here. However, this answer was helpful about 4 months before the others came around and concludes with the same solutions as any of the others. So I'm giving it ^1.