# Getting warning: "componentWillUpdate is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version" when using the react navigation's navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am facing a very strange issue while developing a react native app. I wanted to use navigation for which i added "react-navigation" library. Although, when i am setting the navigationOptions for a route, i am getting the below warning:

```
componentWillUpdate is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.
```

More specifically, it comes when i tried to add the below line:

```
headerRight: (
      <Button>
        <Icon active name="md-color-filter" style={{
            color: '#333'
          }}/>
      </Button>
      )
```

The code for the navigationOptions is:

```
navigationOptions: () => {
  return {
    title: 'App_Name',
    headerRight: (
      <Button>
        <Icon active name="md-color-filter" style={{
            color: '#333'
          }}/>
      </Button>
      )
    }
  }
```

And the respective screen component(HomeComponent) is:

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import {View,Dimensions, Alert} from 'react-native';
import ListComponent from './list/list.component';
import {HOME_SAMPLE_ITEMS} from '../../../constants/data';

function HomeComponent(props: any) {

 return (
  <View>
   <ListComponent data={HOME_SAMPLE_ITEMS}/>
  </View>
 )
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

To be noted, i am using the following versions:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4",
"react-native-device-info": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
```

Can someone please help me resolve the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [componentWillUpdate is deprecated in React, how can I replace it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644862/componentwillupdate-is-deprecated-in-react-how-can-i-replace-it)

Comment: A deprecation warning informs the developer that he's using a feature that will be removed in any future version. There's already some questions about exactly this deprecation, take a look on the link of my previous comment.

Comment: @EliasSoares Thanks for you comment. Well it doesnt seems to be similar to the link you mentioned. I have updated the question and you can see the respective component of the router. Its just a functional component(hook).

Comment: Is your react-navigation updated?

Comment: Consider opening an issue on https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @EliasSoares Yes the package(react-navigation) is updated one only.