# How to detect prop changes before rendering in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a class based component.

I want to pre-compute something before rendering. I don't want to do it for every render, so naturally I would like to detect the prop changes before rendering.

What lifecycle methods should I use? componentDidUpdate triggers after rendering, which is not what I want.

Comment: Potentially related: [componentWillUpdate is deprecated in React how can I replace it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644862/componentwillupdate-is-deprecated-in-react-how-can-i-replace-it)

Comment: you can check the [React Documentation for Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and find out the best  solution for your project.

Comment: You can create a function and call the function on the render method before you do the render any JSX, if the method returns a value you can use that to render any conditional instances that you may have, hope that makes sense

Comment: If you are using a functional component check the useEffect() hook

Comment: @kunalpanchal I don't want to do it for every render. Would like to pre-compute.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez Not using functional component

Comment: @HelloWorld you just can use a flag check to avoid every render

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is the correct way:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
  // Use e.g. nextProps to pre-compute...
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentWillReceiveProps().

Comment: Seems this is a deprecated method and not recommended for usage (according to the docs). Is there any alternative?